# php function always returns null

Tags: php, function, null, return

I've got this php function:

```php
function JobPollAsync(&$fp) 
{
if (($fp === false) or ($fp==null)) {
        return false;
    }


if (feof($fp)) {
    fclose($fp);
    $fp = false;
    return false;
}


return fgets($fp, 1000);
}
```

The problem is that always return `NULL`. At first time, I thought that the `$fp` variable was `null`, but when I put a loop to print whatever was on the variable like this:

```php
function JobPollAsync(&$fp) 
{
if (($fp === false) or ($fp==null)) {
        return false;
    }


if (feof($fp)) {
    fclose($fp);
    $fp = false;
    return false;
}

    while (!feof($fp)) {
       echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
```

}

The printed text was correct. So I don't know what is the reason that forces the `null` value on the return.

I call to this function from another PHP file. The calling is as simple as `JobPollAsync($fp1);` so this can't be the problem.

Anyone who can give me a trace.

Comment: there is a return false inside the if, why?

Comment: Is this the real code? `fgets()` returns `false` in case of error, not `null`.

Comment: Are you sure it returns null? There is no code path at all that does that. fgets returns FALSE on error or EOF.

Comment: Why is this called "async"? Also `($fp === false) or ($fp==null)` is redundant -- the null check is done with double equals, so it will also match `false`.

Comment: @Jon, not when $fp is in fact `null`

Comment: I am not sure. It is a sample code that I found in a web page. I guess is for avoiding to fread() a false value. Anyway, I put print() just above the return and I confirm that the code reaches the return  fgets($fp, 1000);

Comment: @BartFriederichs: `$fp == null` will be true in some set of cases which is a strict superset of the cases when `$fp === false`. Therefore `$fp === false` is redundant.

Comment: @user2038934: Keep in mind that this is **very bad** sample code.

Comment: I put a if on the main program to compare the returned value with null. Like this: if($rv==null) print("has returned null"); Everytime that I run the code, this print shows up.

Comment: @user2038934 - Then it returns `false` almost for sure. Please use `var_dump()` to debug.

Comment: I made the var_dump($rv) and I can confirm that it returns false

Comment: lesson 1 from this: `if($x == null)` is not a good check for `null`. You should always use triple-equal for null tests -- `if($x === null)`.

Comment: Ok. I've changed my code, but still the same error

Comment: I am trying to run this program, just to implement a parallelized php program. If someone thinks that there's a better way to parallelize php, I would thank that. I have tried gearman and I was unable to make it run. So I tried with this because it looked simple to me.